# VBA - Get search preference

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code in which I need to find in range with xlWhole, like below

```
Set oFind = Cells.Find("dummy", , , xlWhole)
```

Problem is, it changes the default search to "Match Entire Cell Contents" when user finds manually next time.

Is there a way I can get search preference of user in my code and set it again after running find in VBA code?

> Like below:
>
> 1. set **pref** = Get search preference
> 2. Find with xlWhole
> 3. Set search preference back to **pref**

Comment: You could finish your macro with `Set oFind = Cells.Find("*", , , xlPart)`

Comment: Yes that is one possible solution. But there is no way to set it the way it was before? E.g. if it was xlWhole before the macro, I want to keep xlWhole only and not to change to xlPart.

Comment: My understanding is that `Find` saves the current values for `LookIn`, `LookAt`, `SearchOrder`, and `MatchByte` in private variables.  I do not know of any method for determining the currently saved valued.